# Pass several arguments as macro in C

Tags: c

Sorry for bad English.

Suppose the code:

```
#define FOO(x,y) FOO ## x
#define BAR A, B
```

`FOO(A, B)` successfully expanded to `FOOA`. But when I write `FOO(BAR)`, the C preprocessor (`gcc -E`) give error

```
error: macro "FOO" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

How I should change `FOO` macro if I want expand `FOO(BAR)` to `FOOA`?

Comment: are you looking for variadic macros ? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define FOO(X, Y) FOO ## X
#define BAR A, B

#define APPLY(F, X) F(X)

APPLY(FOO, BAR)
```

or

```
#define FOO(X) FOO_(X)
#define FOO_(X, Y) FOO ## X
#define BAR A, B

FOO(BAR)
```

Comment: It works! But can you explain why? And why my code doesn't works.